# comparing string two field

Tags: odoo

I just edit my OpenERP, but... I a little confused

how comparing field A and field B but it should not be the same string

this my code

```
def check_description(self, cr, uid,ids, context=None):
    field = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    check = True
    for field in fields:
        check = check and (not field.A==field.B)
    return check
_constraints = [(_check_description, 'Please use a different string',['Warning','Description'])]
```

but...hen I called using on_change. there is no respons

please help me. Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see your code but it is not upto mark it need few imp like below

```
def check_description(self, cr, uid,ids, context=None):
    for record in self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context):
        if record.A==record.B:
            return False
    return True
_constraints = [(_check_description, 'Please use a different string',['Warning','Description'])]
```

You should break the loop as soon as you found miss match if you keep on checking for more records, It will keep on waiting. Second thing the `_constraints` is triggered the save the record so in case of the `on_change` it is certain the  `_constraints` block will be not executed , but if you want same feature on on_change you need to write on_change and trigger the and if values found same use `raise osv.except_osv("", "")` This will show the right message on screen.

Regards.